# Drag-Drop Xml data present in treeview to a canvas in c# wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to drag drop xmldata present in treeview to a canvas but unable to get that.I tried some code and might be missing something.
Below is my code.

```
//handler for mouse move event
private void treeview_mousemove(object sender,MouseEventArgs e) 
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) 
    {
        DataObject data = new DataObject();
        data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, treeView1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        data.SetData("string", treeView1.SelectedItem);
        data.SetData("Object", this);
        DragDrop.DoDragDrop(this,data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
    }
}

//handler for drop event attached in canvas (Don`t know what to do here)  getting 
InvalidOperationException {Logical tree depth exceeded while traversing the tree. This could indicate a cycle in the tree.}
private void treeview_drop(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    UIElement uieve = (UIElement)e.Data.GetData("Object");
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
    {
        canvas1.Children.Add(uieve);
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}

//handler for drag enter event in canvas
private void treeview_dragenter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
}

//handler for dragover event
private void treview_dragover(object sender,DragEventArgs e)
{
    e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.StringFormat))
    {
        string data = (string)e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.StringFormat);
        e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
}
```

All i want is to drop a xml element in the canvas but don`t know what to do.
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can replace the canvas by a listview of your items, define ItemTemplate and DataTemplate. I use it actually in my project. it's more simple for drag n drop functions.

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <!-- Your item representation -->
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Michael,

Comment: Thanks for ur Quick response Michael,but i`am confused what i should do in treeview_drop(i.e drop event)event handler. Actually i want to copy xml data present in treview to a canvas.thanks for ur help.

Comment: Finally got the code working couple of days ago.....sorry for the delay in replying. The thing is all u hav to do is add a label to a canvas and use its content property to get the data from the treeviewItem and set it canvas.children.add property(Code below) 
 //Modified Code private void treeview_drop(object sender,DragEventArgs e) { e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None; if (e.Data.GetDataPresent("String")) { Label label=new Label(); label.content=e.Data.GetData("String"); canvas1.children.Add(label); e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy; } }